# Django class-based views function execution order

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I'm converting some django views to be class based, and so far loving the flexibility.

Most of my views subclass from a parent view `ClubView`. Each subclassed view that needs to handle a `post()` method override needs to have access to the corresponding `club` value.

This value is in the URL, so the request variable has it. However, is there a way for me to grab this value, and fetch the corresponding club object outside of the `post()` method? like a `pre-post()` method or something. Mainly because I don't want to copy/paste `club = Club.objects.get(...`

A more general question -- in what order do all the methods execute in? Django's documentation on this seems lacking.

Answer (score 17):

This [DjangoProject page on Generic Display Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/) seems to be the most helpful, imo.

It covers both ListView and DetailView and explains in detail the methods executed in a class-based display view -- Here's an example of DetailView methods called:

```
setup()
dispatch()
http_method_not_allowed()
get_template_names()
get_slug_field()
get_queryset()
get_object()
get_context_object_name()
get_context_data()
get()
render_to_response()
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you're really doing it upside down. Instead of a central `ClubView`, it's more flexible to have one view class for each of the individual actions/pages. E.g., you might have something like this:

```
class ClubListView(ListView):
    model = Club

class ClubDetailView(DetailView)
    model = Club

# etc...
```

This way you only need to override specific functionality unique to each of those actions, by defining a particular method on the view class which does what you need. E.g. you need to filter the possible Clubs in the `ClubListView` dynamically, based on something from the request? Just override the `ClubListView.get_queryset` method to apply the appropriate filter.

If there is some really peculiar behaviour that needs to be applied to all the views, it depends on what this behaviour really is about: if it's related to this specific model, it should probably best be defined in the model itself, or perhaps its manager; and if it's really something specific to the views, you should write and extend a mixin along with the actual view class.

Comment: Very appropriate. I'm not as familiar with all the predefined class views as I should be. I've only been using `TemplateView` so far.

Comment: I strongly suggest you to get a basic acquaintance with them, as they are there for a reason and will save you a ton of work. Also, get a copy of https://django.2scoops.org/ :-)

Answer (score 2):

`dispatch` is called before `post` - or, for that matter, `get` depending on the request.  Overriding it should let you set extra information.

The docs lack detail - I didn't really get it until I read the source.  But the source is nicely readable except for being spread across multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a `get_club` method in your parent class. You can then use this in your subclasses, and you don't have to repeat the logic.

Comment: True, but this doesn't leverage classes and inheritance. Will try `dispatch` as recommended by Peter